# Getting the text input from Chrome in an Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm completely new to Chrome extensions but I'm trying to create a free, open source extension I feel will help many people.

I have looked through the documentation and haven't been able to find how to get the text being typed in any given tab.

Basically this extension will work very similarly to the dictionary and infact, when certain words arise I would like to underline the text with a different colour to the dictionary and have a context menu with various options when these particular words are found.

I'm not completely new to programming but I am to Chrome and basically JS. I think I'll be OK with populating a context menu and actually checking a word against a db of words to see if it's a matching word. It's just this first hurdle that I'd like some help with.

How do I get real time access to the text to be able to check this against a database of words. I'd also like to underline the text with a colour but will this interfere with the dictionary? If so, are there any suitable alternatives I could use to highlight a word within Chrome?

Comment: To interact with a page, you need to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). There's already a built-in dictionary ( chrome://settings/languages ), why do you want to invent a new one?

Comment: I know I need to use a content script but I'm unaware of what the call is to access the text being typed (like the text I am typing right now). I am not trying to invent a dictionary, or even be anything like a dictionary, it just needs to work in the same way as the dictionary does.

Comment: Getting the text is not too difficult, use the ["input" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.oninput). Styling the text being typed is difficult, because there's no convenient way to style specific pieces of text in an input field.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things that content scripts can do (as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)) are:

- Increase the font size to make text more legible
- Find and process microformat data in the DOM

What they cannot do is:

- Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
- Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages

If you are working with content scripts and trying to compare a word being typed against a DB of words you have in some other extension file, the injected script will have to communicate with these files, which is however not allowed.